# Can`t install python3-venv (unmet dependencies)

Tags: python, apt

I try to install `python3-venv` package with apt-get by following comand:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

But i get some errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-venv : Depends: python3.5-venv (>= 3.5.1-2~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also try to do this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But it is not working, so i try to install `python3-venv` by aptitude end i also get this error.
Could someone help me with this. Becouse i want to use venv, but i have not this package installed yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong, but `venv` supposed to be in default Python distribution try to check it by running

```
 python3 -m venv
```

If it fails, you need to specify subversion of Python. If you are on Python 3.6, try to run

```
 sudo apt-get install python3.6-venv
```

If you are on Ubuntu 16.04, then by default you should have Python 3.5. Run

```
 sudo apt-get install python3.5-venv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`sudo aptitude install <packagename>`

It may not solve the problem but it may  give you more explainded output about the problem and recommendations for fixing it. Also you may try with `-f` option which means:

*Try hard to fix the dependencies of broken packages, even if it means ignoring the actions requested on the command line* (`man` page).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
```

it will setup python3-virtualenv

Comment: I already have virtualenv, but i want to install venv, you don't answer on my question

Comment: install python setup tools and then try again to install python3-venv

Comment: I install it, but trouble in unment dependencies

Comment: show the result of `$ pip freeze` pip3 for python3

Comment: only 1 package started on 'v...' `virtualenv==15.1.01`

Comment: and you have `python3-setuptools` installed?

Comment: No, but when i try to install it `pip install setuptools` i get `requirements already installed`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150526/discussion-between-gahan-and-vladyslav-ushakov).